# OneSignal does not work on mobile

Tags: push-notification, onesignal, web-push

I have a problem getting "OneSignal" web push notifications to work on mobile-chrome browser, it works as expected on PC however, here is the code:

```
<script>
      var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
      OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.init({
          appId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
          autoRegister: false, 
          notifyButton: {
            enable: false,
          },
        }); 

      }); 


    </script>

<script>
        var OneSignal = window.OneSignal || [];
        OneSignal.push(function() {
          OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange',function (isSubscribed) { 
               // if subscribed sends tags
               if (isSubscribed) {
                   window.userPushed = true;
                   OneSignal.sendTag("table", "wasadds_22",function(tagsSent) {
                       console.log(tagsSent);
                   });
               }

          });

          var isPushSupported = OneSignal.isPushNotificationsSupported();

          if (isPushSupported) { 
             //if supported checks if enabled and shows propmpt if is not enabled
              OneSignal.isPushNotificationsEnabled().then(function(isEabled) { 
                  if (isEabled) { 
                      console.log('push notifications are enabled');
                      window.userPushed = true;
                  }else{ 

                      swal({
                        title: 'Subscribe and get benefits!',
                        text: "Press allow ",
                        type: 'success',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, Lets Do it!'
                      }).then((result) => {
                          if (result.value) { 
                              // if user agrees the push prompt shows up
                              OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
                              OneSignal.setSubscription(true);
                          }
                      }); 

                  }

              })
          }; 








      });

    </script>
```

So the problem on mobile-chrome browser that it does not react in any way when I try to trigger push notification subscribe prompt it wouldn't show it, and no errros , also autoRegister does not work either , pls help

Comment: Did You solve this? I have the exact same problem. On PC everything works fine, on Chrome mobile I have the same results.